# How to add javascript to AdSanity Wordpress plugin to rotate images with a fade

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website who's client would like me to adjust our AdSanity plugin to display groups of ads in a rotating image gallery fashion like the ones on [this page](http://vype.com). The leaderboard ads for sure are AdSanity run. I was able to stem from viewing the source that this is the script I need:

```
$(function() {
    var adsLists = $('.adsanity-group'),
        i = 0;
    var divs = new Array();

    adsLists.each(function() {
        divs[i] = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " div").not(".clearfix").hide();
        i++;
    });

    var cycle_delay = 12000;
    var num_groups = $('.adsanity-group').length;

    function cycle(divsList, i) {
        divsList.eq(i).fadeIn(400).delay(cycle_delay).fadeOut(400, function() {
            cycle(divsList, ++i % divsList.length); // increment i, and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
        });
    };

    for (var j = divs.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (divs[0].eq(0).attr('num_ads') > 1)
            cycle(divs[j], 0);
        else
            divs[j].show();
    };

    //////////

    $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 552,
        height: 426,
        navigation: false,
        play: {
            auto: true
        }
    });

    //////////

    $('.three_lines_fixed').each(function() {
        $clamp(this, {
            clamp: 3
        });
    });

    var top_divs = $("#adspace div").not(".clearfix").hide(),
        top_i = 0;

    var top_num_ads = $('#adspace > div').attr("num_ads");
    var top_cycle_delay = 12000;

    function top_cycle() {

        top_divs.eq(top_i).fadeIn(400).delay(top_cycle_delay).fadeOut(400, top_cycle);

        top_i = ++top_i % top_divs.length; // increment i, 
        //   and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
    };
    if (top_num_ads > 1) {
        top_cycle();
    } else {
        top_divs.show();
    }
    var site_url = $("body").attr("site_url");
    $("#brpwp_wrapper-2 ul").append("<li style='text-align: center;'><a class='widgetized_read_more' href='" + site_url + "/2013'>Read More</a></li>")
    /**/
```

And some of that I don't believe I need, like the three_lines_fixed or the slides.  I also have the CSS used for #adspace:
`div.header div#adspace {
    float: right;
    max-width: 728px;
    max-height: 90px; }
    div.header div#adspace img {
      float: right; }`

There is also this CSS:
`div#page .main_content ul.widgets li.adspace {
          display: none; }`

On my site http://dsnamerica.com/eisn/ I want the 300px width ads on the right sidebar to rotate like those on the Vype site. These ads though are not listed with ul and li, they are divs.

So far I've added this to my header.php theme file right before the closing  tag:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/fading-ads.js"></script>`

And in that file (js/fading-ads.js), I have this:

```
function adsanitygroup() {
    var adsLists = $('.adsanity-group'),
    i = 0;
    var divs = new Array();
    adsLists.each(function() {
        divs[i] = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " div").not(".clearfix").hide();
        i++;
    });
    var cycle_delay = 12000;
    var num_groups = $('.adsanity-group').length;
    function cycle(divsList, i) {
        divsList.eq(i).fadeIn(400).delay(cycle_delay).fadeOut(400, function() {
            cycle(divsList, ++i % divsList.length); // increment i, and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
        });
    };
    for (var j = divs.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (divs[0].eq(0).attr('num_ads') > 1)
            cycle(divs[j], 0);
        else
            divs[j].show();

        var top_divs = $("#adspace div").not(".clearfix").hide(),
        top_i = 0;
        var top_num_ads = $('#adspace > div').attr("num_ads");
        var top_cycle_delay = 12000;
        function top_cycle() {
            top_divs.eq(top_i).fadeIn(400).delay(top_cycle_delay).fadeOut(400, top_cycle);
            top_i = ++top_i % top_divs.length; // increment i,
            // and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
        };
    if (top_num_ads > 1) {
        top_cycle();
    } else {
        top_divs.show();
    };
};
}
```

That is my attempt to define the function and clean out what I didn't need. I don't think, no, I know it's not right.  So I'll put my questions in a list, since this post is already wordy.

1) Did I link the js file correctly in the theme's header.php file? It's right before the closing `</head>` tag.

2) Do I need the second CSS part that says "display: none" and if so, how do I change the CSS to work with divs instead of ul and li? Do I just change `div#page .main_content ul.widgets li.adspace {
          display: none;}`
to
`div#page .main_content .widgets .adspace {
          display: none; }`
then add the class .adspace to the widget?

See, I have been trying to get this to work for a couple days now and I've thought so much on it I'm not making cohesive theories anymore, just shots in the dark.  How to solve this?

Comment: A logical [indentation and organization](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) is ***essential*** to not go nuts when programming. I haven't added nor removed nothing from your code, just indented, looks like there's an extra curly brace.